# Adding a string of code to my html by first storing in a variable, then formatting correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a code stored under an exported const in a different file, however I would like to include this as an example in my html if possible...

**my-consts.js**

```
export const myCode = styled.div`
    margin: 100px;
    ...
`
```

**app.js**

```
import {myCode} from './my-consts';

function addCode() {
    const block = document.getElementById('block');
    block.innerHTML = myCode;
}

...

return(
    <button onClick={addCode}>Click me</button>
    <div id="block"></div>
    ...
);
```

This naturally doesn't work as `myCode` is simply a reference to some code, so I am presented with a reference code to the actual code...

I have also tried using `<pre>` around the ref to no affect.

My eventual goal would be like this:

```html
<pre>
export const Button = styled.button`
    font-size: 1.3em;
    background: ${props => props.primary ? "none" : "pink"};
    color: ${props => props.primary ? "pink" : "white"}
    border: 3px solid pink;
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
`
</pre>
```

**I will be changing the code in the display block when I click different buttons, so I do not wish to hardcode this...**

Comment: I did not understand what you want to do actually can you explain that what end result you are expecting.

Comment: I'm new to react. Please let me know if there is an easier way :D

Comment: you want to render that `myCode ` component on button click right ?

Comment: Correct. So that it shows the `export const Button = ` also, if possible

Comment: I m getting confused. you want to render the component or render source code of component ?

Comment: @ShubhanuSharma look at the runnable code snippet. That is exactly what I want to display in a `<div>` container after I click a button.

Comment: check out [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Comment: @Thomas if I am doing `dangerously... = "Button"` it is simply spitting out a reference to the variable, `.sc-bxivhb`

Comment: I this you are asking for ? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-1nplb

Comment: Aha! Wonderbar! I think the issue in the end was with me not quite formatting correctly using `<pre>` and its use with a variable holding the string. Thanks. I will post a modified solution below for future reference.

Comment: Although it seems a bit of a cop-out to have the exact same code, just stringified and exported as a const... But hey-ho, whatever works really. A shame that we can't extract the code as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the comment made by @ShubhanuSharma ([See this sandbox for a quick solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-1nplb)), it turns out that it doesn't seem possible to extract code as a string from a variable; ie. extracting something like `const myVar = 'hello world';` as a full string: `"const var = 'hello world';"`...

So the next best thing is to define a const with this in, essentially copy-pasting the const into a stringified format...

```
export const myconsts = {
    'const1': `const myCode = styled.div\`
    margin: 100px;
    ...
    \``,
    'const2': ... 
}
```

and pulling them in with the function:

```
import {myconsts} from './file';

function addCode(code) {
    const block = document.getElementById('code-block');
    block.innerHTML = myconsts.code;
}
```

with the HTML:

```
<button onClick="addCode('const1')">Click me</button>
<div id="code-block"></div>
```